# mysql select only groups having certain length

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Lets say, i have a table like this:

table1

```
  id | val
_____________
   1 | a
   2 | b
   3 | b
   4 | a
   5 | b
   6 | a
   7 | c
```

and i want to have all rows grouped by `val` but only if the size of the group is 3. So intended result is:

```
[1, a], [4, a], [6, a]
[2, b], [3, b], [5, b]
```

`[7, c]` should be ignored cause the size of it's group is less than 3.

Note, the solution with `having` will return one row for each group and i want to see them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery to identify the `id` values whose groups have three or more members, and then join this to the original table to restrict to the records you want in your result set.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT val
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY val
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) t2
    ON t1.val = t2.val
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query that returns all val's that occur at least 3 times:

```
select id, val
from tablename
where val in (select val
              from tablename
              group by val
              having count(*) >= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT` with `HAVING` should give yu the requested result:

```
select Group_concat(id), value from table group by value having Count(*)>=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT  
    id,
    val as letter, 
    (select count(*) FROM things WHERE val=letter) as number
  FROM things
HAVING number >= 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
 select sel.id, sel.val 
    from 
        (Select COUNT(*) over (partition by val order by val) rowcount, a.* 
    from table1 a) sel
        where sel.rowcount = 3
```